# monitoring number of files in FS

Tags: unix

hi every body 
i am trying to monitoring the capacity of files with shell script using 'df -o i' command

i write in the script the folowing lines

```
#FS_LIST=`df -o i | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $6}' | egrep -v "fd|proc" | tr -d "/"` 
FS_LIST=`df -o i | grep -v Filesystem | grep -v cdrom | awk '{print $6}' | egrep -v "fd|proc" `

for FS in $FS_LIST;
do
        CAPACITY=`df -o i "/${FS}" | awk '{print $5}' | tail -1 | tr -d %`
        LIMIT=80
        DESC="FS=$FS ,  Capacity=${CAPACITY}% , Limit=${LIMIT}%"
#       echo $DESC
        if [ $CAPACITY -gt $LIMIT ] 
        then
                LOGIC_ID="${HOST}_${FS}_${CAPACITY}_Is_Over_Limit"
                echo "LOGIC_ID =  " $LOGIC_ID
                #Send_Alarm_Up;
```

and i recieve this note

```
df: operation not applicable for FSType autofs
df: operation not applicable for FSType ctfs
df: operation not applicable for FSType devfs
df: operation not applicable for FSType fd
df: operation not applicable for FSType hsfs
df: operation not applicable for FSType mntfs
df: operation not applicable for FSType nfs
df: operation not applicable for FSType objfs
df: operation not applicable for FSType proc
df: operation not applicable for FSType sharefs
df: operation not applicable for FSType tmpfs
```

WHAT I DONE WRONG?

Comment: What is `df -o i` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just what it says: those "filesystems" are kernel constructs and don't support the operation.

You could just ignore that by sending stderr to dev null using `2>/dev/null`,
and using the logical-and operator `&&` to only do the following commands when df executes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`df -o i` gives you the number of files on FS see

```
Filesystem             iused   ifree  %iused  Mounted on
/dev/md/dsk/d0        263357 1606147    14%   /
/dev/md/dsk/d5         23401 1222935     2%   /var
```